# How to delete some of scale?

Tags: r

```
x <- seq(0.5, 0.9, length = 400)
y <- dnorm(x,0.7,0.0458)
plot(x, y, type="l",  yaxt="n",ann=FALSE,bty="n")
axis(1, at=c(0.7, 0.8),tick=FALSE)
mtext("Proportions", 1, at=0.9, line=2)
```

I got photo1.jpg with the code,how can i delete some scales(0.5,0.6) in x-axis ,that is to say, to change photo1.jpg into photo2.jpg?

this is a photo1.jpg
[image]

this is a photo2.jpg
[image]